# Solutions of $x^2 ≡ 1 \pmod {p^2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

problem: Let $p$ be an odd prime. Show that the congruence $x^2 ≡ 1 \pmod {p^2}$   has exactly two incongruent solutions, namely $x ≡ +1$ or $-1 \pmod {p^2}$.

what I've done: using definition of modulo, $p^2 \mid x^2{-}1$

but I am stuck right here..

Comment: isn't it the miller rabin primality test?

Comment: @RaghukulRaman It's more Hensel's Lemma consequences !

Answer (score 2):

Finishing where you started, since $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$, and $p^2$ divides this, we have $3$ cases. Either $p^2$ divides $x-1$ in which case we are done, $p^2$ divides $x+1$ in which case we are also clearly done, or $p$ divides $x-1$ and $x+1$. But then $p$ also divides the difference, which is $2$, which is impossible since $p$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

First note the congruence equation  $\; x^2\equiv 1\mod p$ has $1,-1$ as solutions, and that a solution $\bmod p^2$ yields  a solution $\bmod p$ by the canonical morphism:
\begin{align}
\mathbf Z/p^2\mathbf Z&\longrightarrow \mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z, \\
 x+p^2\mathbf Z&\longmapsto x+ p\mathbf Z.
\end{align}
So all you have to prove is that a solution $\bmod p$ lifts to a *unique* solution $\bmod p^2$.

To see this, let $\varepsilon=1$ or $-1$. A solution $\bmod p^2$ can be written as
$$x=(\varepsilon +yp) +p^2\mathbf Z$$
$$\text{and }\qquad\quad x^2=(\varepsilon +yp)^2 +p^2\mathbf Z=(\varepsilon^2 +2yp)+y^2p^2 +p^2\mathbf Z=(1 +2yp) +p^2\mathbf Z=1+p^2\mathbf Z, $$
so that $\;2yp\equiv 0\mod p^2\iff 2y\equiv 0\mod p$. As $p$ is an odd prime, this means $y\equiv 0\mod p$, so $x\equiv \varepsilon\mod p$.